# Histogram of orders by range of dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, presto

I'm trying to create a histogram based on interval of dates and total number of orders but im having a hard time binning it through SQL.

A simplified table can be seen below

| customer_id | Date | count_orders |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01-01-2020 | 5 |
| 1 | 01-13-2020 | 26 |
| 1 | 02-06-2020 | 11 |
| 2 | 01-17-2020 | 9 |
| 3 | 02-04-2020 | 13 |
| 3 | 03-29-2020 | 24 |
| 4 | 04-05-2020 | 1 |
| 5 | 02-23-2020 | 10 |
| 6 | 03-15-2020 | 7 |
| 6 | 04-18-2020 | 32 |
| ... | ... | ... |

and im thinking of binning it into 20 day intervals but the only thing I can think about is do a

```
SUM(CASE WHEN Date BETWEEN <interval1_startdate> AND <interval1_enddate> ...)
```

method per interval which if used into the actual data (which contains millions of row) is quite exhausting. So i need help in automating the binning part.

Desired output would either be

1)

| interval | total_count |
| --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 - 01-20-2020 | 31 |
| 01-21-2020 - 02-10-2020 | 24 |
| 02-10-2020 - 03-01-2020 | 10 |
| ... | ... |

or 2)

| start | end | total_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2020 | 01-20-2020 | 31 |
| 01-21-2020 | 02-10-2020 | 24 |
| 02-10-2020 | 03-01-2020 | 10 |
| ... | ... | ... |

Do you have any ideas?

Comment: So, for your sample data, what are the results you are after?

Comment: What's wrong with the "group by" clause? Something like (PostgreSQL) GROUP BY round(extract('epoch' from Date) / 1.728.000)? Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: *"Which DBMS are you using?"* They OP has clearly tagged [[tag:sql-server]] @aKiRa ...

Comment: Note that first interval in your result contains 20 days (if include both boundaries) and second one - 21. And first one seems to be missing `2 01-17-2020 9` row from sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can group by the (current date - minimum date)/20. For preso something like this:

```sql
WITH dataset (customer_id, Date, count_orders) AS (
    VALUES (1, date_parse('01-01-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 5),
        (1, date_parse('01-13-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 26),
        (1, date_parse('02-06-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 11),
        (2, date_parse('01-17-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 9),
        (3, date_parse('02-04-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 13),
        (3, date_parse('03-29-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 24),
        (4, date_parse('04-05-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 1),
        (5, date_parse('02-23-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 10),
        (6, date_parse('03-15-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 7),
        (6, date_parse('04-18-2020', '%m-%d-%Y'), 32)
)

SELECT date_add('day', 20 * grp, min(min_date)) interval_end,
    date_add('day', 20 * (grp + 1) - 1, min(min_date)) interval_end,
    sum(count_orders) total_count
FROM (
        SELECT *,
            date_diff('day', min(date) over (), date) / 20 as grp,
            min(date) over () min_date
        FROM dataset
    )
group by grp
order by 1
```

Output:

| interval_end | interval_end | total_count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-01-20 00:00:00.000 | 40 |
| 2020-01-21 00:00:00.000 | 2020-02-09 00:00:00.000 | 24 |
| 2020-02-10 00:00:00.000 | 2020-02-29 00:00:00.000 | 10 |
| 2020-03-01 00:00:00.000 | 2020-03-20 00:00:00.000 | 7 |
| 2020-03-21 00:00:00.000 | 2020-04-09 00:00:00.000 | 25 |
| 2020-04-10 00:00:00.000 | 2020-04-29 00:00:00.000 | 32 |

Answer (score 0):

You can get the intervals using CTE and then get the total using `cross apply`.

```
Drop table Tbl
Create Table Tbl (customer_id Int, [date] Date, count_orders Int)

Insert Into Tbl (customer_id, [date], count_orders)
Values (1,'2020-01-01', 5),
       (1,'2020-01-13',26),
       (1,'2020-02-06',11),
       (2,'2020-01-17',9),
       (3,'2020-02-04',13),
       (3,'2020-03-29',24),
       (4,'2020-04-05',1),
       (5,'2020-02-23',10),
       (6,'2020-03-15',7),
       (6,'2020-04-18',32)


;With A As (
Select Min([date]) As start, DateAdd(dd,19,Min([date])) As [end], Max([date]) As [max]
From Tbl
Union All
Select DateAdd(dd,1,[end]) As start, DateAdd(dd,20,[end]) As [end], [max]
From A
Where [end]<[max])
Select A.[start], A.[end], T.total_count
From A Cross Apply (Select SUM(count_orders) As total_count 
                    From Tbl Where [date] between A.[start] And A.[end]) As T
```

Result:

```
start      end        total_count
---------- ---------- -----------
2020-01-01 2020-01-20 40
2020-01-21 2020-02-09 24
2020-02-10 2020-02-29 10
2020-03-01 2020-03-20 7
2020-03-21 2020-04-09 25
2020-04-10 2020-04-29 32
```